# React draggable sliding panel

Tags: javascript, css, react.js, animation

I'm building a sliding bottom panel as a React component, adapting [Phuoc Nguyen's](https://github.com/phuocng) excellent [draggable element tutorial](https://phuoc.ng/collection/react-drag-drop/make-a-given-element-draggable/).

It currently looks like this:

[image: Draggable element in action]

The expected behavior is:

1. User taps on button to open panel
2. Panel slides from the bottom up to fill about 90% of the viewport
3. User can then drag the panel down to close, and when it reaches approx 30% off the top of the viewport it slides down and closes.

Everything appears to be working fine.

I'm interested whether my approach for managing the panel collapse interaction when the `handleMouseUp` function fires could have been more elegant.

Currently I'm using a `setTimeout()` to remove style properties from the element which feels like a bit of a hack.

Below is the function in question and here's the component code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-7nxqaa?file=src%2FFilter.jsx

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```javascript
/*=======================
  H A N D L E  M O U S E  U P
  ===========================*/

    const handleMouseUp = () => {
      // Gets last dy position after move
      const dy = dyRef.current;

      // Resets dy
      setOffset({ dy: offsetTop });

      // Reassigns animation after moving element
      ele.style.transition = 'transform 0.3s ease-in-out';

      // Conditional to say if the current dy position is greater than the desired tollerance
      // then move the element down off canvas (100vh), reset open state to false, and after that
      // remove the in-line transform property ELSE bounce it back to the top, and keep the open state true
      if (dy > tollerance) {
        ele.style.transform = 'translateY(100vh)';
        setOpen(false);
        setTimeout(() => {
          ele.style.removeProperty('transform');
        }, 1);
      } else {
        ele.style.transform = `translateY(${offsetTop}vh)`;
        setOpen(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
          ele.style.removeProperty('transform');
        }, 1);
      }

      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    };
```